# Why can't I get last document from cloud firestore in flutter using provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am banging my head with this and I need your help guys. Please help me with this.

I am currently getting streams from firestore and it's working fine, but the problem is I want to implement pagination now and currently, I can't get the value of the last document which is why I can't use startAfter feature. Have a look into my code

Code on parent page i.e. homepage.dart

```
StreamProvider<List<Cars>>.value(
  value: DatabaseService().getCars(),
  catchError: (ctx, err) => null,
  child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => LastDocumentTracker(),
    child: Scaffold()
```

Code on database Service page:

```
getCars({bool getMore = false}) {
    var collection = carsCollection.orderBy('dueDate').limit(15);
 if(!getMore )   {
   return collection.snapshots().map((event) {


     LastDocumentTracker().changeLastDocument(event.docs.last);
     return _carsListFromSnapshot(event);
   });
 }


  }
```

Now I got a class with ChangeNotifier

```
class LastDocumentTracker with ChangeNotifier{

  List <QueryDocumentSnapshot> _snapshot = [];


  QueryDocumentSnapshot  get getLastDocument {


     return _snapshot.last;

  }


  void changeLastDocument (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc){
    print('Snapshot $_snapshot'); // here I can see the snapshot on console but on other pages where I am listinig its null. 

    _snapshot.add(doc);

    notifyListeners();
  }
 }
```

I was thinking to get the value of the last document from the getter getLastDocument however I am unable to get it because it's always null.

Please help me to implement pagination because I don't want a whole bunch of data to be accessed by users at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you do LastDocumentTracker(), you are creating a new instance of LastDocumentTracker with _snapshot = []. Hence, you are getting the last element as null. Convert LastDocumentTracker into a singleton:

```
class LastDocumentTracker with ChangeNotifier{

  static LastDocumentTracker _instance;

  List <QueryDocumentSnapshot> _snapshot;

  LastDocumentTracker._construct() {
      _snapshot = [];
  }

  factory LastDocumentTracker() {
      if(_instance == null) _instance = LastDocumentTracker._construct();
      return _instance;
  }

  QueryDocumentSnapshot  get getLastDocument {
     return _snapshot.last;
  }

  void changeLastDocument (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc) {

    _snapshot.add(doc);

    notifyListeners();
  }
 }
```

---

## Edit

As you mentioned about the providers, it is better not to go with the singleton answer I provided. Instead, you can replace this:

```
LastDocumentTracker().changeLastDocument(event.docs.last);
```

with

```
final tracker = Provider.of<LastDocumentTracker>(context, listen: false);
tracker.changeLastDocument(event.docs.last);
```

This way, you are accessing the tracker instance that your provider holds. This is better than the singleton pattern I mentioned as it makes the class reusable using the provider.

Note:

- You need context to access provider of that context so pass the context to the getCars method from wherever you are calling it.
- set listen to false otherwise, you won't be able to access getCars from methods like buttonPress callbacks or initState etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I heard this singleton concept for the first time and yeah I am going to research it right now. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: One more question but I have only done LastDocumentTracker() once, which is while defining ChangeNotifierProvider and after that, I am accessing the value using Provider.of(context); Am I still creating a new instance?

Comment: LastDocumentTracker().changeLastDocument(event.docs.last); This line creates a new instance and calls the changeLastDocument method on it.

Comment: If you are accessing from provider, then you are not creating a new instance. You are working with the instance you created in the create field of the provider. The database service page doesn't access the provider in your code. instead, it just creates a new instance and calls the method on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Afridi. My doubt is now cleared and today I learned a new concept too. Hats off to you.

Comment: So it means I don't actually have to use provider then.

Comment: It depends on you what you want to go with. Provider is useful if you are intending to create multiple instances of LastDocumentTracker in your app (Let's say multiple pages use their own LastDocumentTracker). Making it a singleton means that you are limiting it's use to only one instance. It completely depends on what you are trying to achieve. For this answer, I will definitely suggest using providers because it is already set up for you and makes the class more reusable

Comment: I used provider and yeah it worked but again I ran into one more problem. At first, provider is showing a bad state error and after that, it continuously prints the same data again and again like a loop. I think its because I am using stream. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Have a look to this screenshot https://prnt.sc/z7m46x